# Opencart Product Import from Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, opencart

Is there any way to import product from `woocommerce` to `opencart`?
I want to copy some product from a website. I've worked with wordpress, I can scrap product from any site to wordpress. **But now I need to scrap product for opencart** and i'm not much familiar with `opencart`. So I'm thinking to scrap product and import them in `WordPress` first then export them to opencart. Any solution?

Comment: I answered this question before you edited it but now it makes absolutely no sense. Please improve the English.

Comment: Hi Paul, don't get me wrong. A moderator edited my question yesterday, and  sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What does this mean "scrap product"?

Answer (score 0):

You could export from WooCommerce like this:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-csv-importer-exporter/

And then import to OpenCart with any of these (some free, some paid):
https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension&filter_search=import

We've used this one before and it seems good:
https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=17

Answer (score 0):

OpenCart doesn't have a built-in feature for importing products, even from CSV spreadsheets. I was hoping they would integrate this feature on OpenCart 4 but they didn't. Luckily there are some free modules on their marketplace can do the job. I was using this [OpenCart migration module](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=38798), it worked well and helped me a lot. The only problem is that it only supports importing 50 items per batch, however I did some tricks and managed to import all 2000 items into my site.